# How to properly compare two Vector3?

Tags: unity-game-engine

It is necessary to compare two Vector3 in the while loop and when the vectors match, execute the code further. Since xyz is of float type, I have heard that float is not accurate and there may be errors in comparison.
Tell me is it like this? and how to compare it correctly?

I understand this is the wrong option:

```
while (transform.position != target Pos)
{
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target Pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
yield return null;
}
```

have you found the next option, will it be correct? or is there another way?

```
while ((transform.position - target Pos).sqrMagnitude == 0)
{
.........
}
```

I also heard that you can use magnitude, but it is more expensive in performance

Comment: Compare their distance according to a minimum acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [equals operator ==](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) for checking Vector3 equality.

From Unity Docs:

> Returns true if two vectors are approximately equal. To allow for floating point inaccuracies, the two vectors are considered equal if the magnitude of their difference is less than 1e-5.

If you want to use distance, you can use [sqrMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html).
This is more performant than [magnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html) since square roots are not required.

```
var compareDistSqr = 25f;

if ((otherV3 - thisV3).sqrMagnitude <= compareDistSqr)
{
    Debug.Log("less or equal to 5 units away");
}
```